# Call for a specific array to populate <select> drop down on radio button click

Tags: jquery

I have found a way to populate a drop down list with a particular array on a specific radio button click... such as in my example when you click colors. It will display that array or when you click products it will display that array. But I need help getting rid of of let's say the colors array when I call for the products array, or get rid of the products array when I call for the colors array. So basically un-append one array when I call for the other.

```js
var productsArray = ['Cookies', 'Milk', 'Soda'];
var colorsArray = ['Blue', 'Green', 'Red'];

    $('input:radio[name="radioSelection"]').change(function(){
      if($(this).val() === 'products'){
        for(var i = 0; i < productsArray.length; i++) {
          $('#dropdown2').append('<option value='+i+'>'+productsArray[i]+'</option>');
        }
      }
      else if ($(this).val() === 'colors'){
        for(var i = 0; i < colorsArray.length; i++) {
          $('#dropdown2').append('<option value='+i+'>'+colorsArray[i]+'</option>');
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post" id="form2">
      <p>
      <label for="productsRadio">Products</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radioSelection" value="products">
      <label for="colorsRadio">Colors</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radioSelection" value="colors">
      </p>
      <select class="" name="" id="dropdown2">
      </select>
    </form>
```

Here is a js-fiddle example... as you can see when you select the colors radio button and then select the products radio button the dropdown gets filled with both arrays. But I want it to be filled with one array at a time. I want the colors array when the color radio button is selected and then when I want the products array I want the color array to be cleared and for the products array to show up. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, the problem is that it just appends because that's all you're telling the script to do. You're only making it add stuff, you need to also remove stuff.

Try this

```
$('input:radio[name="radioSelection"]').change(function(){ 
  $('#dropdown2').empty();
   ...
```

---

Edit:

```
// this will select the second element (because the first one is = 0) 
for(var i = 0; i < productsArray.length; i++) { 
if(i == 1) { 
  $('#dropdown2').append('<option value='+i+' selected>'+colorsArray[i]+'</option>');
} else { ...do as normal... }
```

Comment: You should empty the select, not `this`.

Comment: Yep, was just about to update it, didn't have the HTML yet when I commented (although it was in the JS-Fiddle).

Comment: I'm new to jquery so how would I make the empty() work with my already written function?

Comment: Literally just add `$('#dropdown2').empty();` to the change function, it will work as intended

Comment: Is there any way to have one of the arrays pre-filled in the dropdown? and have one of the radio buttons already pre-selected when you open that page?

Comment: Yes, could you show how you want the result look like in HTML?

But basically you should just do


`$('#dropdown2').append('<option value='+i+' selected>'+colorsArray[i]+'</option>');` to the one you want.

 I edited my original answer.